# Dealing with chars in C++ (without std::string)

Tags: c++, arrays, char, dealloc

I have this code:

```
char* value = "abcdefg";

char* secondValue = value;
```

The second value will get the addres of value ok? If I delete "value" the secondValue won't be available am I right?

so I should do:

```
char* value = "abcdefg";
secondValue = new char[strlen(value)];
strcpy(secondValue, value);
```

so If I delete "value" no problem.

And finally to dealloc the secondValue I should do:

```
delete[] secondValue;
```

am I right?

Comment: Your questions is tagged and titled C, but `delete` is C++ syntax.  Your question is a bit muddled.

Comment: new/delete? That's C++. Perhaps you should look at std::string.

Comment: ok I'll change the title, I do not have access to std stuff on the component I'm using.

Comment: @okami: Why not? In any case, remake it.

Comment: You should replace `char*` with `const char*`. The reason is outlined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224682/standard-conversions-array-to-pointer-conversion-strings/4224732#4224732).

Answer (score 6):

There are two issues with what you wrote:

1. You cannot delete `char *value = "abcdefg";`, as it is not allocated on the heap.
   To allocate heap memory you use `new` (in C++) or `malloc` (in C).
2. When you allocate memory for a string, you always need one more extra byte for the null termination.

In your case, you should have done:

```
secondValue = new char[strlen(value)+1];
```

Other than that, you are correct

Answer (score 3):

If you are using C++ you are correct, except that you need to make `secondValue` one character bigger:

```
secondValue = new char[strlen(value) + 1];
```

C-style strings are terminated with a `'\0'` character, which also need space to be stored.

If you are using C instead of C++, there is no `new` or `delete[]` and you have to use the functions `malloc()` and `free()` instead:

```
secondValue = malloc(strlen(value) + 1);
...
free(secondValue);
```

In any case note that in the example `value` is a string literal, which cannot be deleted/freed. You should only delete/free what you allocated with new/malloc respectively.

Answer (score 1):

The way you wrote your code:

```
char* value = "abcdefg";
```

The compiler will generate a static string `"abcdefg"`, and `value` will be a pointer to that.  You may assign `secondvalue = value` and then have `value go out of scope, and`secondvalue` will still be valid.

In your example there is no other way to deallocate `value`.

Comment: so if the char* value = "abcdefg"; is inner a struct like struct { char* value; } MyStruct; the "value" data will be a static one even if I delete a object of MyStruct type?

Comment: Yes, **if** you initialized `value` with a static constant.